# How to add resources into jar file

Tags: java, resources, jar

I need to add an exel file into my jar so it's portable. I know the answer is using getClass().getResource.... but i don't have a clue on how to go about using this code.

I have the exel file in the src folder with my class files, it works in netbeans but not when i open the jar file on another PC. i get filenotfound exception

here is the code i have used:

```
public class WindageLogic {

  //....
  public void GetValues() throws Exception
    {


    File exel=new File("src/Calculator/table1.xls");

     Workbook w1; //reads from file

     //reads from file
     w1 = Workbook.getWorkbook(exel);
```

---

Can someone give me the code to implement which will allow me to access this file from the jar application, I've spent all weekend looking up stuff on the internet but i don't understand how i can use these getresource techniques.

thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your excel file is a resource, then you can't use `File` to manipulate it but rather resources, and I believe that it is read-only -- are you sure that this is what you want to do? You could instead load a command line String that tells the program where to start looking for the file, or create a property file that tells where to first look.

**Edit 1**
If you are using JExcel then you can call `Workbook.getWorkbook(java.io.InputStream is)` and get your resource as a Stream via Class's `getResourceAsStream(...)` method.

e.g.,

```
  public void GetValues() throws Exception   {
     Workbook w1; //reads from file
     w1 = Workbook.getWorkbook(WindageLogic.class.
          getResourceAsStream("/Calculator/table1.xls") );
     //...
```

Comment: how do i use resources to access it, and get its file path

Comment: @Faz006: a resource doesn't have a File path. It's loaded from the jar, by the classloader. It's not loaded from a File in the file system. Just use WindageLogic.class.getResourceAsStream("/Calculator/table1.xls") to get an input stream.

Comment: I guess if he put the file in the jar, he only wants to read it.  Unless he has not considered that limitation...

Comment: yes I only need to read this file,  sorry but i'm a total noob at this, do i assign WindageLogic.class.getResourceAsStream("/Calculator/table1.xls") to a variable like a string, or feed it in somewhere.. could you give us a quick example of how to use this, thanks alot, i'm pretty sure this is my solution.

Comment: @JB Nizet: the above was for yourself

Comment: @Fax006: Does the method Workbook.getWorkbook(...) only read from files, or can you use URL's?

Comment: parameter is: getWorkbook(java.io.File file) so i don't think i can use URL

Comment: Then that could be a big problem.  What library is this from? Or is it your own class?

Comment: jxl library,    import jxl.*; is the import i have used

Comment: @Faz006: If you are using JExcel, then the getWorkbook will also accept InputStreams, and so you're back in luck!  Use getResourceAsStream! See edit above.

Comment: can i not somehow obtain the path of the exel file inside the jar and feed it into: File exel=new File(String s); as a string

Comment: @Faz006: **There are no Files in Jar files, period. They just don't exist**

Comment: yes it works!!, i fed it into the workbook as a parameter and bingo!!! thanks mate

Comment: @Faz006. You really need to learn reading javadoc. Most of the questions you've been asking have their answer in the javadoc of java.lang.Class and Workbook.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the getClass().getResource() method to work the resource should be available in the classpath of the application (either packed in one of the jar files or simply on a folder on disk that is included in the classpath).

Depending on what IDE or code building tool you are using there are multiple ways of making sure it's done.

The simplest way is to put the src folder in the run classpath `java -classpath src:%CLASSPATH% <your.class.name>`

Comment: it is packed in with the jar file with the other class files, but i can't access it

Comment: then make sure the path is correct and included in the classpath. Use this command to list the jar entries: `jar -tf <your.jar.file>`

You should probably use this path: "/Calculator/table1.xls" to retrieve the file.

Comment: so would i type this command: jar -tf "C:\dist\WindageCalculator.jar"

Comment: To see the entries in your jar file yes. You must then use the entry as presented in there to load it as a resource (either absolute aka. starting with '/' or relative to the class that is loading the resource aka not started with '/').

Comment: I can use something like: WindageLogic.class.getResourceAsStream("/Calculator/table1.xls") but i don't know how to use it in my code, could you give us a quick example of how to use this,

Comment: I have just placed my exel file in the src folder: http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/6858/javagf.jpg